# WordPress 85% Width Content Div Background

Tags: css, wordpress, background

I manage a WordPress site, and I'm having some trouble applying a custom background behind the main content div. Here's a link to the site: [AccelePedia](http://accelepedia.com). You'll see that the main content div is set to 85% width, and on each side is white space. I've tried everything, but I can't apply a background to that white space. I've included the code below pertaining to the div we're looking at. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. :)

If it helps at all, I'm running Wordpress 3.6.1 with the 2013 theme. (Which I have modified.)

Thanks!

```
/**
* 3.0 Basic Structure
* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

body
{
    background: url(http://accelepedia.com/accimages/background02.png) repeat-x top     left;
    width: 100%;
}

.site {
    background: url(http://accelepedia.com/accimages/background02.png) repeat-x top     left;
    border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-right: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    max-width: 1600px;
    width: 100%;
}

.site-main {
    position: relative;
    width: 85%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.site-main .sidebar-container {
        background-image: url(http://accelepedia.com/accimages/background02.png)
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.site-main .sidebar-inner {
    background-image: url(http://accelepedia.com/accimages/background02.png)
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1040px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background image does not exist:

http://accelepedia.com/accimages/background02.png < this file returns a 404

When I set the following it works:

```
body {
 background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png);
}
```

Comment: Try changing the background color of body like so:
body { background-color: green; }  The image you're using in your question still does not exist on the server, I think you need to either upload it or change the URL